# How to make chat Box in flutter without firebase?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, chatbot

I need to ask doubt through chat box to the teacher in my application. The sent message must be stored in database. How can I achieve this. Please do assist me.

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. You cannot achieve this with Flutter on the Frontend. You need a Backend. So what *can* you do with a Backend? Can you create an API? Can your create and use a database? Where exactly is the point where you are stuck and need help?

Comment: Yes, I have Backend in my server which is called through API. I have created a table for "Ask doubt" in the database. When I send a message, the message must be stored in database and it must retriew answer from the server and display it in the chatscreen.

Comment: Okay. Again, what is the exact spot you are stuck at? Can you write to your table? Can you read from a table? What is your stack, what do you use for realtime communication?

Comment: I have created chat screen but i don't know how to send message and store and also how to retriev message and display.

Comment: Well, I would probably use SignalR and .NET Core for the backend, but there are probably others out there that work just as well.

Comment: Okay. I use here php as server side and MySQL as Backend. I am stuck in how to write code to send and retriew message by passing id through API in flutter

Comment: So you actually need help writing PHP? It is really hard to find out what you *need*. Can you *please* specify what *exactly* you need? Where are you stuck? What is the line of code you sit in front of and don't know how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use socket.io for realtime database.